# Why do we take the positive square root only from $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ when integrating using trig substitutions?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2 \sqrt{16-x^2}}$$
when substituting $\,x=4\sin\theta ,\;\mathrm dx=4\cos\theta\, \mathrm d\theta,\,$ it becomes
$$\int\frac{4\cos\theta\, \mathrm d\theta}{4^2\sin^2\theta\sqrt{16-4^2\sin^2\theta}}$$
then
$$\frac{1}{4}\int\frac{\cos\theta \,\mathrm d\theta}{\sin^2\theta\times4\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}$$
The question is why did we take the positive root of 16 and took it out? as $\sqrt{16} \;is \pm 4 $

Comment: Sorry, I was fixing them the same time you were doing so thats why edits were not made, in a moment

Comment: sorry for that, I didn't notice that I didn't confirm changes, everything is fixed now

Comment: $\sqrt{16}$ is _not_ $\pm 4$. The square root sign $\sqrt x$, with a positive real-valued argument $x$, always means the $positive$ number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. (Otherwise, what does that integral even mean?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote that “$\sqrt{16}$ *is* $\pm4$”. This is wrong. Yes, the number $16$ has two square roots: $4$ and $-4$. But $\sqrt{16}$ stands for the *non-negative* root of $16$, which is $4$. For the same reason, $\sqrt{16-4^2\sin^2\theta}=4\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.

Comment: so $x^2 = 16, x = \pm4$ but $\sqrt16$ is $ 4$ right?

Comment: Yes, both $4$ and $-4$ are solutions of the equation $x^2=16$, but $\sqrt{16}$ only means $4$.

Answer (score 3):

With $x=4\sin\theta$ your integral becomes $\int\frac{4\cos\theta d\theta}{64\sin^2\theta|\cos\theta|}=\frac{1}{16}\int\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(\cos\theta)d\theta}{\sin^2\theta}$ with $\operatorname{sgn}y:=\frac{y}{|y|}$. Luckily, choosing $\theta$ to obtain $\sin\theta=\frac{x}{4}$ lets us arbitrarily choose whether $\cos\theta$ is $\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}$ or $-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{16}}$, so we can choose a constant $\operatorname{sgn}(\cos\theta)$ factor. Since $\sqrt{16-x^2}$ is real only if $|x|\le4$, the most convenient choice is $\theta=\arcsin\frac{x}{4}\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ so, on this half-period of $\theta$, $\theta$ is a monotonic function of $x$ with $\cos\theta\ge0$.